# How to put HTML into button's content?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.5

What I want to achieve is to render a button with view helpers (`form_row` etc.), but I also use FontAwesome icons, so I need to put some HTML into `button`'s content.

The problem is that special chars are converted to HTML entities, so it doesn't behave as HTML anymore.

**What I want:**

```
 <button type="button" name="form[save]"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign in</button>
```

**What I get:**

```
 <button type="button" name="form[save]">\&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-sign-in&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; Sign in</button>
```

**What I'm doing:**

I create a form like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
    // other fields...              
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => '<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign in'))
    ->getForm();
```

And I render this button like this:

```
{{form_row(regForm.save)}}
```

Is it possible to prevent encoding to HTML entites?

**Update:**
The cleanest solution I found since now is to use `raw` filter while overriding `button_row` block template. Is it the best way to do this?

Comment: well, the obvious answer is "use a link on a div and disguise it as a button", but if you want to use a button, you can still target with the same classes by adding the style of fa-sign-in to that button or use :before selector. Otherwise, I'd suggest to stick to HTML entities

Comment: It's a form - I can't use a link or div. Anyway `button` is designed to contain html (in opposite to input). I also can't style the button, because fa changes the font so the `Sign in` would have wrong font.

Comment: you can attach an action via JS to a link in a form, it's done every day. You could also use an input type=submit . I agree with what you say about button and the ability to contain HTML, but you're in a pickle, so commenting on alternatives if you don't want to use HTML entities

Comment: if you want to use your system the raw filter is the unique solution but isn't the best way. I'm using the moopa way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `{{form_row(regForm.save)}}` to render the button is more simple to render it directly in the view like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn green"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign in {{ 'form.global.button.sign_in'|trans({}, 'form') }}</button>
```

otherwise you can create a button and/or icon twig extension (like did in MopaBootstrapBundle) to implement it in the form component (and to reuse it everywhere).

Comment: I've checked `MopaBootstrapBundle` source. So possible solutions are the Mopa's way and my way described in question update. For know I'll leave it like it is (my way), but thanks for answer, it's useful.